# NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, myfaces, trinidad

I am using IBM WAS 7.0 and myfaces.version 1.1.5 but when i run the application following error is triggered. but the same code is working fine in some other environment(environment with same configuration).

```
[8/9/16 14:36:58:634 IST] 0000001f viewhandler   E   Error Rendering View[/jsf/search.jspx]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager(RootRenderingContext.java:193)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UIXComponentUINode.getRenderer(UIXComponentUINode.java:379)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UIXComponentUINode.renderInternal(UIXComponentUINode.java:166)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UINodeRendererBase.encodeEnd(UINodeRendererBase.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:693)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:304)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:321)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.html.CellFormatRenderer.encodeAll(CellFormatRenderer.java:102)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:224)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:693)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:304)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.html.RowLayoutRenderer.encodeChild(RowLayoutRenderer.java:110)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:321)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.html.RowLayoutRenderer.encodeAll(RowLayoutRenderer.java:88
```

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.NullPointerException can occure on WAS 7 when security is enabled and provisioning is disabled, you can apply the fix pack 8.0.0.11 and 8.5.5.7 see (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI39369) for more details